# Binding Firebase with Redux

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux, react-redux

I am building a `react-redux` app with `firebase`.

Here is my action creator:

```
export function fetchUser(uid) {
  let ref = firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid)
  return dispatch => {
    ref.on("value", (snapshot) => {
      let obj = snapshot.val()
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_USER,
        payload: obj
      })
    })
  }
}
```

In my React Component, I want to be able to chain on it and wire up another action. So something like:

```
componentWillMount() {
      let userId = 'some user id'
      this.props.fetchUser(userId).then(()=> {
        this.props.updateUser() // perform another action after the fetch is complete
      })
}
```

I am having a hard time doing this.

- One problem is that Firebase `on` event listener doesn't implement a promises interface.
- I dont want to move the subsequent action inside `fetchUser` action as other components can be calling `fetchUser` as well for other purposes.

I feel this should be straight forward but I am new to both redux as well as firebase so all help will be appreciated.

Comment: "One problem is that Firebase on event listener doesn't implement a promises interface." `on()` can fire multiple times, a promise can resolve only once. There is no way `on()` could be a promise. If you only care about a single value, use `once()` which *does* return a promise.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I agree and understand that. However still, I do want a callback each time `on` fires in my component so that I can fire another action. Using `react-redux`, I can get it as changes to `props` but that doesn't feel right.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am finding making firebase work with redux pretty hard tbh :) Opened an issue directly: https://github.com/firebase/reactfire/issues/115

Comment: This example could be useful: https://github.com/kenfire/react-redux-firebase-template

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you don't get a Promise returned from firebase doesn't really seem to be your issue. You can return a promise in your action creator then use the resolution of that to kick off `.then()` in your `componentWillMount()`. We've done something like this:

```
export function fetchUser(uid) {

  let ref = firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid);

  return dispatch => {
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
      ref.on("value", (snapshot) => {
        let obj = snapshot.val();
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_USER,
          payload: obj
        });
        resolve();
      })
    });
  }
}
```

Also, if you want promises from firebase, you can use [.once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once). This might actually work better for you so you don't have a perpetual listener on the `/users` ref.

Comment: This wont work. `on` can fire multiple times. `resolve` wont work in all invocations subsequent to the first one as the promise is already resolved.

Comment: Are you calling the `fetchUser` action each time you want to get a value? If so, this should do exactly what you want it to. We are using this pattern in our production app and it works exactly as intended. I'd recommend you try it rather than just saying it won't work.